# T-SQL count loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to count all the columns in a database table and union the counts together using an iterative method for 15 columns instead of what I have shown in the example.

i.e.

```
select count(columnname1)
from schema.tablename
where columnname1 is not null and datasource = xxx


union all

select count(columnname2)
from schema.tablename
where columnname1 is not null and datasource = xxx

union all
....
```

The result should returns a count per columns for 15 columns and stored in a table.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results because I don't know you are trying to achieve.

Comment: the `WHERE` clause is actually redundant. `COUNT()`  is counting non-null value

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want to know which count goes with which column? An unnamed column of integers doesn't seem very useful unless your only interest is whether all of the columns have the same number of non-null values.

Answer (score 1):

A variation of the dynamic sql approach which outputs 3 columns (the count, the column name and the table name). You can specify the table name(s) you want in the where clause and you can optionally also filter which columns you want to consider.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
SELECT @sql += N'
UNION ALL
SELECT ''' + t.name + ''' as tname '
  +  ', ''' + c.name + ''' as cname '
  + ', COUNT(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ') as rows '
  + ' FROM ' + t.name 
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE t.name IN (N'foo')
--AND c.name LIKE N'columnname%'
  ;

SET @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 11, N'');
-- select @sql
EXEC (@sql)
```

This variant does not include "where [colname] IS NOT NULL" as this is redundant given the `COUNT()` will just ignore NULL values and it is unlikely that these where clauses will enhance overall performance as table scans are likely in all or most cases.

see example: https://dbfiddle.uk/EAez4OGR